# How can I reduce vertical space in the rows of my table?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with how to make different strings of different sizes. It doesn't fit, or I'm doing something wrong. Below I will post an example of how it should be, and how I did. I would be very happy if anyone can advise. Yes, and by the error code itself, you can say, I'm just learning, I accept any criticism :)

I need to make row sizes in certain areas the same. For example, where 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. you need to make them narrower, as in the first image. And so on all table to understand with the size of lines.

[image: Example table]

[image: My table]

**Here's what happens if I change the padding size**

[image: Edited]

**CODE:**

```css
body {
  background-image: url(./h3back.jpg);
}

td {
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.t1t {
  border-top: solid 3px;
}

.t1r {
  border-right: solid 3px;
}

.t1b {
  border-bottom: solid 3px;
}

.t11r {
  border-right: solid 1px;
}

.t11b {
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
}

.t1bd {
  border-right: 1px;
  border-right-style: dashed;
}

.t1tx {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.t2tx,
.t1tx {
  text-align: center;
}

.t3tx {
  text-align: right;
}

.t4tx {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" class="t1t t1r t1b t4tx">Ⅱ. Облік проведення занять та їх <br> відвідування </td>
        <td class="t1t t1r t11b t11w" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t1r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td colspan="4" class="t1t t1r t11b t12w t2tx">Тиждень №__________</td>
        <td class="t1t t11b t13w t2tx" rowspan="4">Для нотаток</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="t1r t11b t2tx">Пропущ. занять (годин)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11r t11b t2tx">за тиждень</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t1r t11b t2tx">від початку</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t1b"></td>
        <td class="t1b wt12 t3tx">Навчальна дисципліна,<br>викладач, заклад</td>
        <td class="t11r t11b t1tx">Усього</td>
        <td class="t11r t11b t1tx">З непов.<br> причини</td>
        <td class="t11r t11b t1tx">Усього</td>
        <td class="t1r t11b t1tx">З непов.<br> причини</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" class="t1r t1b t2tx t4tx">№ <br> з/п</td>
        <td rowspan="2" class="t1r t1b t2tx t4tx">Прізвище та ініціали <br> студентів</td>
        <td class="t11b t1r t2tx">Аудит.</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t1r t1b t2tx t4tx">Дата</td>
        <td colspan="8" class="t1r t1b t2tx t4tx">Пн.</td>
        <td class="t11r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t1b"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r t2tx t4tx">1.</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r t2tx t4tx">2.</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r t2tx t4tx">3.</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r t2tx t4tx">4.</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r t2tx t4tx">5.</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd "></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t1b"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="t1b t1r t4tx">Усього відсутніх<br>(запізнилося)</td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td colspan="5" class="t1b">Пропусків<br>у группі</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="t1b t1r t4tx">Підписи викладача<br>і старости</td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t1b"></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing the vertical padding on the table cells seems to get close to what you're after. We can then put larger padding on the rotated cells to keep them spaced.

It might be easier to rotate div elements inside the table cells instead of the cells themselves. That would make padding work properly.

To give empty rows height as if they contained text we can use a pseudo-element with whitespace content.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(./h3back.jpg);
}

td {
  padding: 3px 10px; /* <----------------------------------HERE */
}

td:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block; /* force empty rows to have height */
}

td.t1tx {
  padding: 25px 10px; /* <----------------------------------HERE */
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.t1t {
  border-top: solid 3px;
}

.t1r {
  border-right: solid 3px;
}

.t1b {
  border-bottom: solid 3px;
}

.t11r {
  border-right: solid 1px;
}

.t11b {
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
}

.t1bd {
  border-right: 1px;
  border-right-style: dashed;
}

.t1tx {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.t2tx,
.t1tx {
  text-align: center;
}

.t3tx {
  text-align: right;
}

.t4tx {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" class="t1t t1r t1b t4tx">Ⅱ. Облік проведення занять та їх <br> відвідування </td>
        <td class="t1t t1r t11b t11w" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t1r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td colspan="4" class="t1t t1r t11b t12w t2tx">Тиждень №__________</td>
        <td class="t1t t11b t13w t2tx" rowspan="4">Для нотаток</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="t1r t11b t2tx">Пропущ. занять (годин)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11r t11b t2tx">за тиждень</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t1r t11b t2tx">від початку</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t1b"></td>
        <td class="t1b wt12 t3tx">Навчальна дисципліна,<br>викладач, заклад</td>
        <td class="t11r t11b t1tx">Усього</td>
        <td class="t11r t11b t1tx">З непов.<br> причини</td>
        <td class="t11r t11b t1tx">Усього</td>
        <td class="t1r t11b t1tx">З непов.<br> причини</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" class="t1r t1b t2tx t4tx">№ <br> з/п</td>
        <td rowspan="2" class="t1r t1b t2tx t4tx">Прізвище та ініціали <br> студентів</td>
        <td class="t11b t1r t2tx">Аудит.</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t1r t1b t2tx t4tx">Дата</td>
        <td colspan="8" class="t1r t1b t2tx t4tx">Пн.</td>
        <td class="t11r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t1b"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r t2tx t4tx">1.</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r t2tx t4tx">2.</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r t2tx t4tx">3.</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r t2tx t4tx">4.</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r t2tx t4tx">5.</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd "></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t1b"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="t1b t1r t4tx">Усього відсутніх<br>(запізнилося)</td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td colspan="5" class="t1b">Пропусків<br>у группі</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="t1b t1r t4tx">Підписи викладача<br>і старости</td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t1b"></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: td.t1tx {
  padding: 25px 10px; /* <----------------------------------HERE */
}
Thanks for that, great tip, I'll use it. But about the indents in other parts, then look at the post, I edited and indicated in the picture what exactly is wrong

Comment: Oh, I think I figured out how to do what I need. Make a class to change the size of the indent and assign it to the rows that I need

Comment: See my update. You can easily set the minimum row height with a pseudo-element.

Answer (score 1):

I made a new class called "a", then I specify new paddings.

```css
body {
        background-image: url(./h3back.jpg);
      }
      
      td {
        padding: 15px 10px;
      }
      
      table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font-size: 20px;
        
      }
      
      .t1t {
        border-top: solid 3px;
      }
      
      .t1r {
        border-right: solid 3px;
      }
      
      .t1b {
        border-bottom: solid 3px;
      }
      
      .t11r {
        border-right: solid 1px;
      }
      
      .t11b {
        border-bottom: solid 1px;
      }
      
      .t1bd {
        border-right: 1px;
        border-right-style: dashed;
      }
      
      .t1tx {
        transform: rotate(270deg);
      }
      
      .t2tx,
      .t1tx {
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      .t3tx {
        text-align: right;
      }
      
      .t4tx {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
     .a{
       padding: 7px 7px;
     }
```

```html
 <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" class="t1t t1r t1b t4tx">Ⅱ. Облік проведення занять та їх <br> відвідування </td>
        <td class="t1t t1r t11b t11w" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t11r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="t1t t1r t11b" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td colspan="4" class="t1t t1r t11b t12w t2tx">Тиждень №__________</td>
        <td class="t1t t11b t13w t2tx" rowspan="4">Для нотаток</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="t1r t11b t2tx">Пропущ. занять (годин)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11r t11b t2tx">за тиждень</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t1r t11b t2tx">від початку</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t1b"></td>
        <td class="t1b wt12 t3tx">Навчальна дисципліна,<br>викладач, заклад</td>
        <td class="t11r t11b t1tx">Усього</td>
        <td class="t11r t11b t1tx">З непов.<br> причини</td>
        <td class="t11r t11b t1tx">Усього</td>
        <td class="t1r t11b t1tx">З непов.<br> причини</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" class="t1r t1b t2tx t4tx">№ <br> з/п</td>
        <td rowspan="2" class="t1r t1b t2tx t4tx">Прізвище та ініціали <br> студентів</td>
        <td class="t11b t1r t2tx">Аудит.</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t1r t1b t2tx t4tx">Дата</td>
        <td colspan="8" class="t1r t1b t2tx t4tx">Пн.</td>
        <td class="t11r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t1b"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r t2tx t4tx a">1.</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r t2tx t4tx a">2.</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r t2tx t4tx a ">3.</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r t2tx t4tx a">4.</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r t2tx t4tx a">5.</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t11b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t11b"></td>
        <td class="t11b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1bd "></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t11r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t11r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t1r t1b"></td>
        <td class="t1b"></td>
      </tr>
      
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="t1b t1r t4tx">Усього відсутніх<br>(запізнилося)</td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td colspan="5" class="t1b">Пропусків<br>у группі</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="t1b t1r t4tx">Підписи викладача<br>і старости</td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t11r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t1b t1r"></td>
        <td class="t1b"></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

  </table>
```

Comment: see my code you can change the padding to yours at the class"a"

Comment: Yeah, thanks you, that a good tip, but @isherwood already helped me with this :)